# Can I use GAE's CloudStorageTools on non app engine projects?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My app is using Google cloud storage to store images. My app is not on google app engine.
I would like to be able to upload a large image and have google serve resized versions of the image as explained here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/images

According to the link above, I need to use:

```
$object_image_file = 'gs://my-bucket/myfile.png';
$object_image_url = CloudStorageTools::getImageServingUrl($object_image_file,
                                            ['size' => 400, 'crop' => true]);
```

The problem is that CloudStorageTools is part of app engine SDK, and I can't get it to work on a regular server.

How can I use this class outside of the app engine?

Is it possible to use google cloud storage and have it resize the image?

I'm using PHP.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot use it outside of App Engine.